# Reactjs change font size color

Tags: reactjs

Pretty much finish with this practice component but I want to add a detail to the `span id="fontSizeSpan"`when it reaches its max or min value to turn red. I got the feeling it got something to do with `style` but still I haven't been able to make it work.

Here's the functions:

```
class FontChooser extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {hidden: true, size: 16, max: 40, min: 4, bold: false};
}

toggle(){
    this.setState({hidden: !this.state.hidden});
}
makeBold(){
    this.setState({bold: !this.state.bold});
}
plusSize(){
    if (this.state.size < this.state.max) {
        this.setState({size: this.state.size + 1});
    }
}
minusSize(){
    if (this.state.size > this.state.min) {
        this.setState({size: this.state.size - 1});
    }
}
resetSize(){
    this.setState({size:16})
}
sizeColor(){
    if (this.state.max) {
        this.setState.size({color: 'red'})
    }
}
```

And the Render:

```
render() {
    
return(
    <div>
     <span id="textSpan" onClick={this.toggle.bind(this)} style={{ fontWeight: this.state.bold ? 'bold' : 'normal', fontSize: this.state.size}}>{this.props.text}</span>
       <div hidden={this.state.hidden}>
        <input type="checkbox" id="boldCheckbox" onClick={this.makeBold.bind(this)}/>
        <button id="decreaseButton" onClick={this.minusSize.bind(this)}>-</button>
        <span id="fontSizeSpan" onDoubleClick={this.resetSize.bind(this)} style={{color: this.sizeColor.bind(this)}}>{this.state.size}</span>
        <button id="increaseButton" onClick={this.plusSize.bind(this)}>+</button>
       </div>
    </div>
);
}
```

}

**NOTE:** Does somebody knows how could I make the child div to be next(**left**) to the `<span id="textSpan"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To turn it red when it reaches min or max, I would do this:

1. Just before the `return` of the `render()` method I would do:

```
const isMinOrMax = (this.state.size == this.state.min || this.state.size == this.state.max)
```

2. In the style of the span I would add

```
color: isMinOrMax ? 'red' : 'black'
```

That's it :)

Answer (score 0):

You are wrongly using setState.

```
sizeColor(){
    if (this.state.size > this.state.max) {
        this.setState({color: 'red'});
    }
    else {
        this.setState({color: 'whatever color you like'});
    }
}
plusSize(){
    if (this.state.size < this.state.max) {
        this.setState({size: this.state.size + 1});
    }
    this.sizeColor();
}
minusSize(){
    if (this.state.size > this.state.min) {
        this.setState({size: this.state.size - 1});
    }
    this.sizeColor();
}
```

and inside render

```
<span id="fontSizeSpan" onDoubleClick={this.resetSize.bind(this)} style={{color: this.state.color}}>{this.state.size}</span>
```